# Undo diffget in vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff, undo-redo, git, merge

Say I have a merge conflict in Git, and try to resolve it with **vimdiff** using `diff3` view. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Initial State]

Now while resolving, I want to `diffget` once from `LO` see how it looks like, undo, and then `diffget` from `RE`. Another situation is that I have `diffget`ed from the wrong place, say `LO`, so I want to undo and `diffget` the correct one, say `RE`.

So first of all I do `:diffget LO` and get what is expected:

[image: After <code>:diffget LO</code>]

So far everything is ok, but now I want to undo the last `diffget`, to `diffget` from `RE`. So I undo with `u` and get to what I had before (though, note the highlighting difference):

[image: After undo]

And now simply `diffget` from `RE`:

[image: After <code>diffget RE</code>]

So I got one additional redundant `octocat` line `diffget`ed from `RE`.

Below is what I was expecting:

```
        +----------+------------+
        |  actual  |  expected  |
        +----------+------------+
        |    cat   |    cat     |
        |    dog   |    dog     |
   ??   |  octodog |   octodog  |
  ----> |  octocat |   octocat  |
        |  octocat |            |
        +----------+------------+
```

So my question is, why is this happening? And how can I achieve the behaviour I expected?

Comment: How do you show the bottom split ? FYW I tried the same without the bottom split and I didn't get any trouble

Comment: This is the `diff3` view, so that the middle one is the Common Ancestor, and the bottom one is the Merge Result. I got it with git config, `merge.tool=vimdiff` and `merge.conflictstyle=diff3`.

Comment: I see, here is a recording of a vimdiff https://asciinema.org/a/26318, it doesn't have the diff3 render but may do what you want.

Comment: @Nobe4 Thanks for your responses. Seems like running `:diffupdate` after `:diffget ...` solves the issue.

Comment: n9code: This is strange because AFAIK `:diffupdate` only update the display of the diff, not the text ...

Comment: Yes your are right. But in this case I will not need text update. As I can do the following and get desired result: `:diffget LO` -> `:diffgetupdate` -> `:diffget LO` -> `:diffget RE` -> `:diffget LO` ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29120/discussion-between-nobe4-and-n9code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(cf [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29120/discussion-between-nobe4-and-n9code))

It seems that at some point, running the `diffupdate` command solves the problem.

`:diffupdate` updates the current diff view. It changes the diff colors to match the new state between files. It also update the folds, that are displayed to keep the diff buffer relatively small.

Comment: Additionally, it might be helpful to have Vim automatically execute `:diffget` when you save the file (working copy in this case). This way, when you undo, and then save, the diff will be automatically updated.   For example:   `autocmd BufWritePost * if &diff | diffupdate | endif`

Comment: *`diffUpdate`.`diffGet` on save would be weird :p